# how to unlock myicloud without the recovery key

Tags: iphone

how to unlock myicloud without the recovery key I took a screenshot of it but then got locked out of my iPhone and now the iPhone is lockedto myiCloud

Answer (score 0):

All Apple ID recovery goes through https://iforgot.apple.com

Please use that website to login to your account. If you're unable to complete the steps presented, then you cannot recover your account.

There's no simple answer to write here, since every account is configured differently. This is why using the website linked is better, since it is specific to your account.